# Jquery not receiving any form values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using cluetip to open popups with a pm system in. When i post the pm Jquery is not receiving the values in any fields. Here is a JsFiddle can anyone help?
The html form

```
<div class="interactContainers" id="private_message1">
<form action="javascript:sendPM();" name="pmForm" id="pmForm" method="post">
<font size="+1">Sending Private Message to <strong><em><?php echo "$username"; ?></em></strong></font><br /><br />
Subject:
<input name="pmSubject" id="pmSubject" type="text" maxlength="64" style="width:90%;" />
Message:
<textarea name="pmTextArea" id="pmTextArea" rows="8" style="width:90%;"></textarea>
  <input name="pm_sender_id" id="pm_sender_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sessionid ?>" />
  <input name="pm_sender_name" id="pm_sender_name" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user ?>" />
  <input name="pm_rec_id" id="pm_rec_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $profileid ?>" />
  <input name="pm_rec_name" id="pm_rec_name" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $username ?>" />
  <input name="pmWipit" id="pmWipit" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $thisRandNum ?>" />
  <span id="PMStatus" style="color:#F00;"></span>
  <br /><input name="pmSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
<span id="pmFormProcessGif" style="display:none;"><img src="../_Images/loading.gif" width="28" height="10" alt="Loading" /></span></form>
</div>
```

the jquery

```
$('#pmForm').on('submit', function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    var pmSubject = $("#pmSubject").val();
    var pmTextArea = $("#pmTextArea").val();
    var url = "../_Scripts/private_msg_parse.php";
    if (!pmSubject) 
    {
        $('input[type=submit]',this).removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#jqueryReply").html('<img src="../_Images/round_error.png" 
            alt="Error" width="31" height="30" /> &nbsp; Please type 
            a subject.')
            .show().fadeOut(6000);
        return false;
    } 
    else if (!pmTextArea) {
        $('input[type=submit]', this)
            .removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#jqueryReply").html('<img src="../_Images/round_error.png" 
            alt="Error" width="31" height="30" /> &nbsp; Please type in your 
            message.')
            .show().fadeOut(6000);
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#pmFormProcessGif").show();
        $.post(url, $('#pmForm').serialize(), function (data) {
            $("#jqueryReply").html(data).show().fadeOut(10000); 
            $("#pmTextArea").val('');
            $("#pmSubject").val('');
            $("#pmFormProcessGif").hide();
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RKN39/

Thanks

Comment: why are you using `<font></font>` tags

Comment: Can you format the JavaScript to be... readable?  Debugging it a lot easier with meaningful use of whitespace.  That could also make it more clear what you're even asking, because currently the question doesn't make a lot of sense.  JavaScript (and by extension jQuery) doesn't "receive posted values."  Server-side code does.

Comment: cluetip plugin clone element (with ID) and as IDs must be unique, your inputs value are still the first one which is still equal to empty string. Simple fix, using FORM context: http://jsfiddle.net/RKN39/2/

Comment: @David I think for readability, it'd be much better if he separated the `javascript` from the `html` actually.

Comment: I feel like the fiddle is missing some things.

Comment: @Zero21xxx what do you feel its missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about cluetip but I don't think that the form field values are being passed since they are inside a container that is hidden - .interactContainers has a css value of display:none. You can keep that designation and try something like

```
    $('#private_message').on("click", function(){
        $('.interactContainers').css('display','block')
    });
```

or maybe there is a way to integrate that into your cluetip code?